# Remove an entry out of a std::list while iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove elements in a list when a condition is met in a `std::list`. What I have read in the Reference about the return value of the `erase` function:

> An iterator pointing to the element that followed the last element
>   erased by the function call. This is the container end if the
>   operation erased the last element in the sequence.
>
> Member type iterator is a bidirectional iterator type that points to
>   elements.

I have put this example together:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        typedef std::list<std::string> string_list_t;
        string_list_t list;
        list.push_back("test1");
        list.push_back("test2");
        list.push_back("test3");
        list.push_back("test4");
        list.push_back("test5");
        list.push_back("test6");
        list.push_back("test7");
        list.push_back("test8");

        for (string_list_t::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        {
                std::string &str = *it;
                std::cout << "Checking " << str << "..." << std::endl;
                if (str == "test4")
                {
                        std::cout << "Found test4!" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                        it = list.erase(it);
                }
        }


    return 0;
}
```

It does not give me the expected output, instead it gives me:

```
Checking test1...
Checking test3...
Checking test5...
Checking test7...
```

Can someone help me figuring out what I understood wrong? Somehow it skips every second element...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are skipping the element after the deleted one.

You should use *either* `it = list.erase(it);` or `++it`, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

When you erase an element from a `std::list`, do not increment the iterator returned by the [`std::list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) method. You will not just skip the next element, you may just end up incrementing an `end()` iterator.

Change your loop to:

```
for (string_list_t::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); )
                                                                //^^ Not incremented
        {
                std::string &str = *it;
                std::cout << "Checking " << str << "..." << std::endl;
                if (str == "test4")
                {
                        std::cout << "Found test4!" << std::endl;
                        ++it;           //increment
                }
                else
                {
                        it = list.erase(it);
                }
        }
```

See it [Live Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/212aa5bdfa4aafdb)